# C# Date Time Picker to Text?

Tags: c#, date, time, datetimepicker, picker

Im trying to get a text from a file into date format for a label.

What i currently have works great for a DateTimePicker however im wanting to now use a label to display the date rather than a DateTimePicker.

This is what currently works when getting the value to a DateTimePicker:

```
        dateTimeMFR.Value = this.myKeyVault.MFRDate;
```

and this is what im attempting to make work in a label:

```
        DateTimePicker myDate = new DateTimePicker();
        myDate.Value = myKeyVault.MFRDate;
        txtMFR.Text = myDate.Text;
```

Thanks for any help on the matter.

Comment: So many correct answers, upvotes for everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the *format* which you want to show the date in. If it should be default user format, then this:

```
txtMFR.Text = myKeyVault.MFRDate.ToString();
```

is sufficient. 
You can also manually format `DateTime` as date or time by calling `ToShortTimeString` or `ToShortDateString` or combinations of them. Or you can provide one of the predefined string formats as explained  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/). For example:

```
txtMFR.Text = myKeyVault.MFRDate.ToString("T");
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why are you not just calling `DateTime.ToString`.

```
txtMFR.Text = myKeyVault.MFRDate.ToString();
```

If you want [custom format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can specify it like this

```
txtMFR.Text = myKeyVault.MFRDate.ToString("yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

First pick the format you would like to display it as:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Then do:

```
txtMFR.Text = myKeyVault.MFRDate.ToString([put your selected format here]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
label1.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

This will do it.